# Show both Overridden VisualForce Page and Standard Salesforce Page to Partner Community Users based on condition

Tags: partner-communities, nooverride

I need custom object for which the New/Edit/View buttons have been overridden to a VisualForce page.

The  VF Page has logic to redirect the user to either Salesforce page using nooverride=1 or to another VF Page. This redirection is not based on recordType but based on value of a custom field.

I need to implement the same for Partner Community users.

How can this be achieved in Partner Community? Is noooveride=1 supported in Partner Community?

Answer (score 0):

Strange requirement.  But I support you could just have the controller check for a url param and return a pagereference to the "New Record" page.  There might be some snags with the community url being slightly different than the internal url.

Something like this:

```
if(url param here){
PageReference p = new PageReference('url of new record page');
p.setRedirect(true);
return p
}
```

Further architecture questions to consider: What advantage does the standard New Record page have that you can't reproduce on the custom page?  And what does the custom page do that can't be done with a standard page?  Removing this fork in the road reduces complexity...